# Index was outside the bounds of the array. Snake Game

Tags: c#

yet again I am having problems. So, I have put in my code and currently I am trying to add food in to my Snake Game, sadly it is not working. Whenever I debug it it tells me
"Index was outside the bounds of the array"
Here is the section of code.

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        paper = e.Graphics;
        food.drawFood(paper);
        snake.drawSnake(paper);

        for (int i = 0; 1 < snake.snakeRec.Length; i++)
        {
            if(snake.snakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
            {
                food.foodLocation(randFood);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the specific part.

```
if(snake.snakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a typo:

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < snake.snakeRec.Length; i++)
//             ^^^
```

That appears to be the number one.. instead of the variable `i`. That means the condition will always be true.. therefore your index variable will become larger than the array at some point.

Comment: Thank you good sir. I would NEVER have caught that. Thank you for your time.